# How to read MIME file

Tags: email, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need some help to download email attachments from S3 bucket, email formats are MIME files. How can I read this email file and download attachment? Any good source is appreciated too

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name="3c1bd1393c7543cd9f38c1ff26d474ab.snappy.parquet"
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename="3c1bd1393c7543cd9f38c1ff26d474ab.snappy.parquet"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <f_l6z42itv0>
X-Attachment-Id: f_l6z42itv0
```

Comment: What language are you going to parse these files in?  There are email parsing libraries for a wide range of languages.

Comment: python, probably using email library.